# Use of Indexer.xml in Magento

Tags: magento2, indexer

What is the use of indexer.xml ?
I mean what it does?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

In magento indexer.xml file is used to declare custom index under etc directory.
It define id as well as class of indexer that contain business logic. like below:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">             
    <indexer id="sagar_popular" view_id="sagar_popular_order" 
    class="Vendor\sagar\Model\Indexer\Popular">
   <title translate="true">Popular Products</title>
   <description translate="true">Sort products in a category by 
  popularity</description>
   </indexer>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I cannot understand--
Why custom index is required?